# powershell script running from local server but not from client in active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo, winlogon

i have this simple powershell script, that gets info from AD and stores them on a file on the desktop at logon
It is in the logon Group Policy.
When i log on in the server with my user (not admin) the scripts works perfectly.
When i log in from a client machine it runs, creates the file, but no info in it.
any ideas?

```
$strName = $env:username
$ObjUser = Get-ADUser  -Properties * -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $strName} | select displayName, title, telephoneNumber, mail, sAMAccountName, fullname

$strtitle = $objuser.Title
$strphone = $objuser.telephoneNumber
$stremail = $objUser.mail

$folderlocation = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")

$Filenam  = "$folderLocation\\test.txt"
$SigName  = $normalName + "-" + $strtitle + "-" + $strphone + "-" + $stremail | Out-File $Filenam
```

Comment: Are the AD cmdlets installed on the client?  You need to install [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) to get them.

Comment: 1) I installed RSAT
2) enabled the "Active Directory Module For Windows PowerShell" in control panel in windows 7
3) import-module activedirectory

Comment: 1) I installed RSAT
2) enabled the "Active Directory Module For Windows PowerShell" in control panel in windows 7
3) import-module activedirectory
4) Get-Module -ListAvailable gives me that ActiveDirectory is installed
5) i run from the client the ps1 powershell script from the powershell ISE (don't know if i can do this) and i have the error:
The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
 path is correct and try again.

Comment: For recent versions of PowerShell, the AD module should load automatically, but for older versions, you may need to add `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` at the top of your script.  If you just open a PowerShell prompt and run 'Get-ADUser`, does it give the same error?

Comment: thanks guys, adding the Import-Module ActiveDirectory at the top of the script did the job :)

Comment: @boxdog - Please write your last comment as an Answer.  Since it *was* the solution.   user3448380 - please accept it when he does.

Comment: @T-Heron.  Done.

Comment: @user3448380 please accept the answer you confirmed to properly assign the credit.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) is installed n the target system and that the  "Active Directory Module For Windows PowerShell" is enabled in Control Panel, then add the following to top of your script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Typically, PowerShell loads modules automatically when required, but sometimes you need to explicitly tell it to.